# Async/Await with mysql in node.js returns only undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days and have basically gone through everything I could find here on stackoverflow, maybe I'm missing something since I've been staring at it for so long.

I have a nodejs file which loads user data via sql and sends the result to the main file (server).

I call this function again with an async function to get the value of the row.

```
var sql = require('./db');
let h = /^[a-zA-Z-_.\d ]{2,180}$/;

 async function getdata(hash){
if (!hash || !hash.match(h)) {
    return {type: "error", msg:"Verarbeitungsfehler, bitte laden Sie die Seite neu.", admin:     false}
}else{

    const response = await sql.query('SELECT * FROM bnutzer WHERE hash = ?',[hash], async     function(err, result, fields){
        //console.log(result)
        return await result
    })

    }   
}




module.exports = { getdata };
```

```
async function getvalue(h){

    try{

     var result = await admin.getdata(h); 
    console.log('1'+result);
     if(result{

        console.log('2'+result)
     }

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Could not process request due to an error');
        return;

    }
}

getvalue(user.ident)
```

The data from the sql query are correct and they also return the correct result when I output them in the console, however they are not passed with return to the function with which I call the code, it comes only undefined, I have the feeling that await here somehow does not wait for the result, what am I missing here? I have already tried it with several constellations that I could find on the internet, unfortunately I have not yet come to the goal.

I already tried not writing the sql query with async/await and only writing the calling function with async/await, no result. I have tried various sql query with and without sql callback. I hope someone can point me to what I am twisting or missing here.

Comment: Could be getdata function not returning expected result to the calling function.,

One potential issue is that the sql.query takes a callback function as a parameter. This means that you cannot use the await keyword to wait for the result of the query

Comment: I already try this with a sql.query without a callback function, this seems to work but i dont get the value from row(data) i only get the query data that the query worked and which arguments and so on just the general info.

Comment: Syntax in if statement is incorrect. dunno if this is relevant but

 `if(result{

        console.log('2'+result)
     }`

you need to close the if statement

Comment: Hey, this was just a typo cause i deleted a comment before i posted the code here, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your async callback function will just return it in `response` variable in a good case. But anyway , use return await in nested async function is not a best way. So , your `result` will become a `response` variable , you're not doing anything with it and it just will stay as it is , without return value. So , then you'll have a plain function and `undefined` as a result of it's execution. Since you're not returning anything from there.

I suggest to :

```js
const sql = require('./db');
const h = /^[a-zA-Z-_.\d ]{2,180}$/;

async function getdata(hash){
  if (!hash || !hash.match(h)) {
    return {type: "error", msg:"Verarbeitungsfehler, bitte laden Sie die Seite neu.", admin:     false}
  }else{
      try {
      const response = await sql.query('SELECT * FROM bnutzer WHERE hash = ?',[hash]);
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Cold not proceed with query');  // Wwhatever message you want here
    }
  }   
}


module.exports = { getdata };
```

And then :

```js
module.exports = { getdata };

async function getvalue(h){
    try {
      const result = await admin.getdata(h); 
      console.log(result, 'Here will be your successfull result')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err); // Do anything you need , console.log / transaction rollback or whatever you need.
        throw err;  // No need to return it. You can also make some custom Error here , via "new" operator 
    }
}

const value = await getvalue(user.ident); // It's async , so you should wait.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I still do not get the right result, however I have now used the package mysql2 and mysql2-promise and there your code works fine and gives the desired result, no idea why with the first mysql package nothing would work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the method in which you are executing query is incorrect you should do something like this

```
 async function getdata(hash){
    if (!hash || !hash.match(h)) {
        return {type: "error", msg:"Verarbeitungsfehler, bitte laden Sie die Seite neu.", admin:     false}
    }else{
        
      try{
        const response = await sql.query('SELECT * FROM bnutzer WHERE hash = ?',[hash])
        return response
      }
      catch(error){
        throw Error(error.message + "error")
      }
     } 
 }
```

try this you cant mix callback and await like the way you're doing just await for the result and in case of error it'll handled by catch block in this case

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, i already try what you write and the Problem here is that i dont get the row (data) from the sql table, the response i get is only from the query but not the result from the row.